# Can't enable SVN in Visual Studio Code on Linux

Tags: svn, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code 1.36.1 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04. My SVN executable is installed under `/usr/bin/svn`. Now I installed the "SVN" extension to VS Code and added these lines to `settings.json`:

```
"svn.enabled": true,
"svn.enableProposedApi": "none",
"svn.path": "/usr/bin/svn",
"svn.showOutput": true
```

Then I restarted VS Code, in the "Output" tab I get the following message:

```
Using svn "1.9.7" from "/usr/bin/svn"
```

So it seems the SVN extension in VS Code is enabled and can find my SVN executable. However, when I go to the "Source Control" tab it still gives me the following message:

```
No source control providers registered.
```

So ... how can I enable/register the SVN extension, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

The next thing you need to do is to add the local copy of your SVN repo (with the *.svn*) folder to your VS Code workspace. It has to be the top folder when displayed on the Explorer panel, like this [spamassassin repo](https://www.apache.org/dev/version-control.html#anon-svn) I checked-out from Apache:

[image]

Notice that the Output panel now shows the `svn stat` command.

Next, the SVN extension adds its own **Subversion** panel aside from the existing **Source Control** panel. It will only appear once you have a valid SVN repo added to the workspace.

[image]

Finally, when you make changes to any of the files, the changes should now appear in the **Source Control** panel, with the corresponding actions to commit, view changes, etc.

[image]